# proving the divergence of a sequence using definitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Use appropriate definitions to show that, $\cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 10 -\sqrt{n} = -\infty $

So we need to find a function N(M) for each $M>0$ such that $\lvert 10 - \sqrt{n}\rvert > M $

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use definitions to divergence or convergence so any general tips would be greatly appreciated!

But I'll give this problem a shot...

$\lvert 10 - \sqrt{n} \rvert \ge \lvert 10 \rvert - \lvert \sqrt{n} \rvert = 10 - \sqrt{n} > M$

So $10-M<\sqrt{n}$ or $(10-M)^2 < n$

Would N(M) = max{$10, (10-M)^2$}?

Comment: so I can say that for $n \ge 100$, $\lvert 10 - \sqrt{n} \rvert = 10 - \sqrt{n}$ and then proceed? Which would make the answer max{$100, (10-M)^2$}

Comment: Ryan, your method is right, but your condition is not. When proving $\lim_n a_n$ goes to $-\infty$, you need to show that $a_n < M$ eventually, for every $M$. Be careful how you write this up. Remember, you need to say that $\forall n > N(M)$, that $10 - \sqrt{n} < M$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M < 0$; then $10 - \sqrt{n} < M$ iff $\sqrt{n} - 10 > |M|$, which holds iff $n > (10 + |M|)^{2}$; so for all $n \geq \lceil (10+|M|)^{2} \rceil +1$ we have $10 - \sqrt{n} < M$.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom out a little. What you want to show is: for any arbitrarily large-negative $M$, the function $10 - \sqrt n$ is *eventually* smaller than $M$ – that is, it *get smaller* than $M$ and *stays smaller* than $M$, from some point on (i.e. for all $n >$ some $N$).

That is: for all $M < 0$, there's an integer $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, 
$$10 - \sqrt n$ < M$$
or equivalently,
$$10 - M < \sqrt n \tag{*}$$
So given large negative $M$, let $N = (10 - M)^2 + 1$; then (*) is true for $n \ge N$.

Intuitively: $f(n) = \sqrt n$ is a strictly increasing and unbounded function of $n$. But for any given $M$, $10 - M$ is fixed; so from some point $N$ on, $f(n)$ is always bigger than $10 - M$.